PowerBI Columns Conditional Formatting with Matrix Object
I have the following table that I summarize in a Matrix visual object in Power BI.
Initial Table
I would like to create a conditional formatting where the value on each cell gets a different color based on the max value of the column itself (higher is better).
Initial Matrix PBI
Let's take P1 column as example.
I would like to get P1 "green" in R_C since is the maximum.
P1 in R_B should be yellow (let's say 0.7<max).
And P1 in R_A in red as it is the worst values (0.3<max).
Expected result
Thanks for the support!
